# React JS - How to check if .find returns an empty list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to find one object, and that's the object that was created on a certain date. I can't find any reference for .find, so I am sort of guessing. There are no "Logs" created today, so hello should show up. But it doesn't. I think I am checking for the wrong thing or am using .find incorrectly.

```
addLog(){
    if(Logs.find({createdAt: Date.now()}).fetch() == null){
      return(
        <p>Hello</p>
      );
    };

  },
```

Comment: what library are you using? Is this *find* from ES6, ImmutableJS, underscorejs, etc...? And what your `fetch` does and usually returns?

Comment: If you add `console.log(Logs.find({createdAt: Date.now()}).fetch());` before your if statement, what does console output look like?